# Redirect to sign in page with additional param with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a Ruby on Rails application that uses Devise gem for authentication.
I have the following scenario:

1. User visits http://localhost:3000/surveys.
2. User is redirected to http://localhost:300/sign_in?return_to=http://localhost:3000/surveys.

How can I add this additional parameter to sign in to url when redirecting?

Comment: Do you really need to add the extra parameter or it is enough that you redirect to the current page after successfull sign in?

If the second case is true, hope the following link helps you achieve this.
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add extra parameter to the redirection URL,

```
redirect_url =  "http://localhost:3000/sign_in" + "?return_to" + "#{request.original_url}"
redirect_to redirect_url
```

Answer (score 0):

in a more "rails way" you can do it like this

```
redirect_to new_user_session_path(return_to: surveys_path)
```

it add's a new get param to the url generated, named return_to and you can set that value to another path like in your case, surveys_path or surveys_url